# Handle network changes on android 7 Nougat

Tags: android, networking, event-handling, android-broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

Is there any way to handle wi-fi or cellular networks enable/disable on android N. I've tried to add broadcast receiver with intent-filter `"android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"`, but it's deprecated for N and higher.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#connectivity-action

Comment: Thanks, I've read it many times, but I've not seen this     `Apps that are running can still listen for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE on their main thread by registering a BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver().`

Comment: The idea there is that if your app is already running for other reasons, you can keep track of connectivity changes via broadcasts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The network changes listener implementation for android N and high

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
```

Many thanks to
[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)
for useful answer.

Comment: But it will be killed once the activity which registers this receiver is killed?

Comment: @ParasWatts just use the application context

Comment: I am doing this now using the firebase job dispatcher. Working fine.